# How can I filter the effects of a variable from a correlation matrix?

Tags: reference-request, matrices, na.numerical-analysis

I have a correlation matrix (it contains 500 columns and 500 rows) and I would like to make an other correlation matrix in which one variable (and its influences) is filtered from the initial matrix. How should I do this? I would be very happy if you could paste a link too where I can find a mathematical article about this topic:)